# How do I include the homepage in the Sphinx TOC?

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

Let’s say I’ve got a Sphinx project with the following sources:

```
index.rst
installation.rst
templating/
    index.rst
    module.rst
    fieldtype.rst
```

index.rst (the homepage) has the following TOC tree:

```
.. toctree::
   :titlesonly:

   installation
   templating/index
```

I want my template to include a sidebar that lists all 3 top-level pages (homepage, installation, templating/index).

I've tried adding a second, hidden TOC tree in the homepage:

```
.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   index

.. toctree::
   :titlesonly:

   installation
   templating/index
```

That actually gives me the desired result, *except* that it makes the `next` variable set to the current page. So this code in my template:

```
Next up: <a href="{{ next.link }}">{{ next.title }}</a>
```

…always outputs the homepage link from the homepage. No good.

I’ve always tried to hardcode the actual homepage link right into the sidebar of the template:

```
{% set homeClass = 'current' if pagename == 'index' else '' %}
<ul class="{{ homeClass }}">
    <li class="toctree-l1 {{ homeClass }}"><a class="{{ homeClass }} reference internal" href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
</ul>
{{ toctree() }}
```

That also works, except that I don’t want to force the docs to be accessed on the webroot of a web server – I want them to work from the file system too.

I can’t simply set the URL to “index.html” because that won’t work when you’re in a file within templating/.

Am I missing something obvious? There must be a way to get the homepage into the TOC, without breaking `next` links and with a dynamic path that works on a local file system, even from within subfolders.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Turns out the answer was hiding in plain sight on Sphinx’s [TOC tree page](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/toctree.html):

> The special entry name `self` stands for the document containing the toctree directive. This is useful if you want to generate a “sitemap” from the toctree.

Adding `self` to the TOC tree did the trick perfectly! And if you place it in a separate, hidden toctree directive, it won’t show up on the homepage’s table of contents either:

```
.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   self


.. toctree::
   :titlesonly:

   installation
   templating/index
```

Comment: and `Home <self>` renames the self link to "Home"

Comment: Unfortunately `self` doesn't include any subheadings (see https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2103).

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible for you to rename your Sphinx project's root toctree page, or, alternatively, the templating/index page? The `master_doc` variable lets you name the file in your project that contains the root toctree directive, and it doesn't have to be called `index.rst`... in our documentation project to get around a problem very like this, we have a `template/index.html` file and our root toctree page is actually called `reference.rst`.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with that is getting the TOC back onto the homepage. I tried using an rST 'include' directive but that didn’t work...