# Make the heading levels of documents automatically dependent of the depth's levels of the (sub(sub(...)))folders they belong to

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, sections, toctree

Suppose I have:

- a `foo0.rst` file at the root (`source`) of my `sphinx-doc` source folder,
- a `foo1.rst` file in a subfolder `subfolder1` of `source`,
- a `foo2.rst` file in a subfolder `subfolder2` of `subfolder1`,

that is:

```
$ tree source
source
├── foo0.rst
└── subfolder1
    ├── foo1.rst
    └── subfolder2
        └── foo2.rst
```

all with the same content:

```
This a title
============
```

Now, if the `index.rst` contains:

```
Welcome to Test's documentation!
================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3
   :caption: Contents:

   foo0
   subfolder1/foo1
   subfolder1/subfolder2/foo2
```

`make html` gives:

```
Welcome to Test’s documentation!

Contents:

    • This a title
    • This a title
    • This a title
```

that is all the headings are sections.

What I would like to get instead is the following:

```
Welcome to Test’s documentation!

Contents:

    • This a title
      ◦ This a title
        ▪ This a title
```

that is the heading of:

- `foo0.rst` being a section,
- `subfolder1/foo1.rst` being a subsection (and not a section),
- `subfolder1/subfolder2/foo2.rst` being a subsubsection (and not
  a section).

My question is therefore: is it possible to make the heading levels of
documents belonging to (sub(sub(...)))folders automatically depend on
the depth's levels of the folders they belong to?

Comment: My answer was writing thinking about generating HTML output not LaTeX...I don't know how Sphinx translates the toctree to LaTeX. But if the toctree gives you too much trouble the easiest solution is still building a reST bullet list with links and cross-references where you structure the levels exactly as you want.

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style applied to the `toctree` **[entries](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5/markup/toctree.html#directive-toctree)** is dependent on the [theme](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/theming.html) you are using. The theme's CSS will apply a style to the entries that Sphinx translated into `<ul>` and `<li>` depending both on their place within the *["document hierarchy"](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5/markup/toctree.html#directive-toctree)* given how you chain the `toctrees` and how your [section structure](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections) in the individual `.rst` files is organized.

For example, inspect the HTML elements Sphinx generates. The `toctree` will be a `div class="toctree-wrapper compound"` with each level of sections being named `<li class="toctree-l1">` then `<li class="toctree-l2">`, etc...

One way to achieve what you want would be to surround a given `toctree` using a `.. class::` directive (as [show here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900626)) and apply a [custom style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32079202). But that would then impact the style of any other `.rst` files you want to include as entries in that `toctree`.

In any case, you will incur in extra work and potentially loose automatism if you refactor your project.

There is also [one possible workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16302843), using the `:hidden:` option together with the [`:include:`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include) directive. If you declare a hidden `toctree` before a visible `toctree` the *"document hierarchy"* can fix the position of an entry for you in the hierarchy. Afterwards the visible `toctree` without the `:hidden:` option will render `.rst` file entries as a `<li>` element having a fixed position in the hierarchy. (A thorough example can be seen [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63653074)).

It can be done, but you will be working against the characteristics of the `toctree`.

The prevalent solution is writing your `.rst` files and sections depending on how you want the `toctree` to display. (This approach has all the advantages with the only drawback of putting restrictions on how you write the `.rst` files). It's probably the preferable solution rather than trying to adapt the CSS styles or using workarounds.

---

**EDIT:**

What I wrote before is valid, but probably too general. So I'll give one possible solution to the example. If you want the following:

```
Contents:

    • This a title (foo0)
      ◦ This a title (foo1)
        ▪ This a title (foo2)
```

A simple option is using a chain of `toctree`s. You can hide the `toctree`'s that are lower in the document hierarchy if you don't want to see them.

`index.rst`

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3

   foo0
```

and in `foo0.rst`

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3
   :hidden:

   subfolder1/foo1
```

and in `subfolder1/foo1.rst`

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3
   :hidden:

   subfolder1/subfolder2/foo2
```

The result will be as you specified.

Comment: The trouble, at least with the second solution, is I have about a thousand files that are currently included in the main `index.rst` file. So I would have to edit all of them to write the `toctree` directive and the path of the right subfile to include: rather impossible.

Comment: The `toctree` directive is meant to list `.rst` files and sections (only!) Your aim is to expand functionality so that for every directory level an implicit section level be *"somehow"* included. The `toctree` directive doesn't have that functionality. There are a couple of *"relatively low-effort"* ways to achieve the result you want, but they still require extra work and will become a constraint of the overall organization of your project. There is no magic solution for this that avoids drawbacks, adds constraints, and requires extra work. I have to ask: Why not write extra `.rst` files?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé are [the underlines](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections) of the reST sections in the subdirectories all the same? Or did you use different underlines as the directories went into deeper levels?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the point of the "extra `.rst` files": do you mean extra "root" files in each directory? About the underlines, they are all the same. My use case is a `DokuWiki` site I'd like to export as a `Sphinx-doc` one, the `DokuWiki `source files being exported thanks to `pandoc`

Comment: This is an interessting use case I hadn't seen before, just to confirm you export `DocuWiki` -> `Pandoc` -> `reStructuredText` using the converters [in this list](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc). That's why you end up with lots of `.rst` files... Afterwards the final step is generating `reStructuredText` -> `Sphinx` -> [one of the several output formats in this list](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html)?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé There are several possible solutions for this problem. The easiest would be 1 `.rst` per directory using a toctree with a glob pattern [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51955585) and [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28774689) and chaining those toctrees up to the one in `index.rst`. The documentation doesn't say if Sphinx would recognize a [recursion glob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14798263), I tried looking at [the source code](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3.x/sphinx/directives/other.py#L42) but can't figure it out (I'd have to test it).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé another solution -because `pandoc` gives you a toctree with a full list of the `.rst` files- is to write a simple `for` loop (in whatever language) where you convert that list of paths from a `.txt` to a nested [reStructuredText bullet list](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#bullet-lists) with a [document reference](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-doc) to each file. Then use the `:hidden:` option in the toctree and simply copy-past the nested bullet-list of references.

Comment: Indeed, the route I'm using is `DocuWiki` → `Pandoc` → `reStructuredText`. The final step is `reStructuredText` → `Sphinx` → `html`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé The above solutions are relativly easy and low-effort. The best solution depends on your aim. Do you simply want an export/migration of the existing wiki without development/refactoring happening in the future? (Sphinx has many applications, the usual is to document a code project under development.) Deciding the best course of action depends on what application you'll be using the Sphinx project for, and where you'll deploy the docs. (For example, on ReadTheDocs the toctree is tied to the sidebar so you'd want to make an effort to conserve it.)

Comment: I'll have a deeper look at these solutions later (too busy right now): thanks! At some point, the `DokuWiki` site should be migrated and closed so no development/refactoring would happen in the future. This site is a LaTeX FAQ and should be deployed on GitLab pages.

Comment: I guess at the end of your answer, `subfolder1/subfolder2/foo2` should be `subfolder2/foo2`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé ["This directive inserts a “TOC tree” at the current location, using the individual TOCs (including “sub-TOC trees”) of the documents given in the directive body. Relative document names (not beginning with a slash) are relative to the document the directive occurs in, absolute names are relative to the source directory. (...)"](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree) I'll have to think about it later and possibly revise the detail, right now I can't spare the attention. Thank you for the warning.

Comment: About "convert that list of paths from a .txt to a nested `reStructuredText` bullet list with a document reference to each file", do you mean a bullet list as nested as the file in the corresponding path?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé yes that is exactly what I mean. The nested bullet list solution has the advantage of being easy to implement programmatically if you are generating from a fixed (and very large but complete) list of links. (N could be in the thousands, so solving it with 1 `for` cycle might not be elegant/minimalistic, but it gets the job done easily.)

Comment: The trouble with this conversion into a nested `rst` bullet list with a document reference to each file is that the table of contents is empty.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé there are 2 directives sometimes called *"table of contents"*, one is the `toctree` the other is the [reST TOC](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents). By constructing the bullet list, it becomes the "table of contents" (there wouldn't be much sense to having 2 TOC's). So exactly what TOC do you mean in what context?

Comment: I mean the ToC in the sidebar.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé as I had said, the ToC in the sidebar is connected programmatically to the `toctree` (but not all themes use a ToC in the sidebar, and you hadn't specified if you wanted it). In that case using the solution that preserves the toctrees should be followed.